# angular nested categories refresh router problem

Tags: angular, categories, router, reload, angular9

I have a module that looks like this:

**categories-routing.module.ts***

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CategoriesComponent }, // this path does not reload
  { path: 'new', component: CategoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmailGuard] },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: CategoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmailGuard] },
  {
    path: 'category', redirectTo: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: CategoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CategoriesRoutingModule { }
```

And **categories.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesComponent {

  public categories!: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private nav: NavbarService,
    public cs: CategoryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.route.data.pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.cs.loadCategories();
      })
    );
  }
```

Navigating through the directories works fine however, when I go to the '' path, it does not reload and only displays the last path.  I have tried subscribing to the activated route etc in many different ways to the exact same result. I also would prefer to reload the component, not the page.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had some bad logic in my loadCategories() function.  Two days of research at least I learned more about routers than necessary!